# Ruby on Rails puts in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm working on a web application that has a view where data is fetched and parsed from a text file (the textfile is only available at the backend, not to the user).  I've written a function that takes in the text file and converts it to an array of strings, it's called `txt_to_arr`. Then I have another function `line_fetcher` which just calls `txt_to_arr` and outputs a random string from the array.

In my view, I call the controller's function as so: `<% line_fetcher %>`.

I've put both `txt_to_arr` and `line_fetcher` into the view controller's helper `rb` file, and when I run `rails s`, the random string is not rendered at all. I've also tried `<% puts line_fetcher %>`

I've checked in Bash that the function does output random strings from the text file, so the function does work correctly. Also, the text file being parsed is in the `public` folder. Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't show how you're actually doing anything. `<%= xxx %>` is how to render a string.  Puts writes to stdout, which isn't part of the rendered html. Might be a good idea to check out some Rails tutorials.

Comment: Please show the code for text_to_arr and line_fetcher.  Also, is it a function or a ruby method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<%= %>` to output something in your view, so:

```
<%= line_fetcher %>
```

Comment: Oddly enough, I tried this before and could have sworn it didn't work..but trying it again after reading your suggestion it worked..thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**In ERB**: The `<% %>` signify that there is Ruby code here to be interpreted. The `<%= %>` says interpreted and output the ruby code, ie display/print the result.

So it seems you need to use the extra = sign if you want to output in a standard ERB file.

```
<%= line_fetcher %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the code in the controller and assigning the output to a variable using

```
a=`line_fetcher` (note the backtics) as detailed at
```

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

and then `<%= a %>` in your view.

and place the file in the root of your rails app

Comment: Hey thanks for the link about executing shell commands in Ruby, I think it will come in handy for this web app in the future:)

Answer (score 1):

Simple `erb` like `<%= line_fetcher %>` would work good for simple variables.

But if you want output of any model/database instance then do:

```
<%= ModelName.first.inspect %>
```

Note the `inspect` word.

And in case of using `HAML` do:

```
=ModelName.first.inspect
```